# help filtering data in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Im new to cakephp and Im having a little problem querying data.
I have a User model and a Product model in a many to many relation.

What I what is simply for my Products/Index action to only get the products associated to that User (the user is stored in session) and not all Products (which is what it does by default).

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to [set up the relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1000/Models#hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM-1044) properly, the rest is automatic.

Model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Product' => array( /* set up relationship */ )
    );
}
```

Controller:

```
$this->User->recursive = 2; // just to make sure, shouldn't be necessary
$user = $this->User->read(null, $userId);

debug($user);
/**
 * $user['User'] contains the user data
 * $user['Product'] contains associated products
 */
```

Comment: but how do i get the data to the view?? I need to view data to be populated with a bunch of products related to the user thats logged in... rememebr I am trying to do this in products/index

Comment: @NachoF It seems you're missing the fundamentals of Cake. Please follow [the tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1535/Create-a-Posts-Controller) until you understand the basic Model->Controller->View flow.

Comment: @Nacho Try to `bake` all your views (I think you have done this already). Look at the `/users/view/` controller and views. It essentially does what you want. Once you understand how it works it should be easy to adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$products = $this->Product->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.id' => $user_id_from_session
    )
));
```

Comment: it's a many to many relation.. User.id is not a field in the Products table... the query is giving me error cause it's not referencing the Products_Users table at all